# Django PostgreSQL setting with separated credential file?

Tags: django, postgresql, psycopg2, django-settings

I want to migrate my django's database from MySQL to PostgreSQL.
Previously I've used database configuration options just like this example from [Django website](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/databases/#connecting-to-the-database).

The MySQL engine on database setting has options: 'read_default_file', so I can separate my database credential on external file.

Now I'm ready to switch to PostgreSQL with psycopg2 engine, but I can't find the similar options like read_default_file.

Is there any solution for this?

Or may be I should change to other database engine of PostgreSQL which has this options? Thanks

Comment: It's should not be that hard to understand it, here check out this [wiki post](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Converting_MySQL_to_PostgreSQL) on how to convert mysql database to postgresql, try and google for it, you will found some examples quickly

Comment: @petarP, I don't think the OP is asking about that process. It's pretty smooth with django. He is asking about django configuration.

Answer (score 5):

`read_default_file` is purely a mysql thing. It cannot be used for postgresql. The closest equivalent in postgresql is the [.pgpass](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/libpq-pgpass.html) file which is a file that needs to be created in the home directory of the user running the psql client. That defines the user's password.

When you are using django in development creating a file in your your home directory would do the trick. But in production you are not supposed to run the django dev server. Production WSGI servers run under restricted user accounts that may not have a home directory. In that case you need to use the `PGPASSFILE` environment variable to tell django where to look for the password.

Comment: I understand that `read_default_file` is mysql thing, but my main focus is how I can separate between Django setting and PostgreSQL credentials. I thought there was an 'OPTIONS` for psycopg2 engine that can separate the credential. I will try to find the possibility to use the `PGPASSFILE` environment on the PaaS.

Comment: If your main focus is on not putting credentials on the settings file, that's indeed done by enviorenment varaibles.

Comment: Is this sorted out then?